# Percentage of the same column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the percentage of total in SQL
I've got

> customerID, quantity

What i have tried is:

```
SELECT 
   customer_id, 
   sum(quantity) / (quantity * 100)
FROM MyTable
Group by customer_id
```

Comment: Maybe this link will help you : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/sql-percentage-calculation

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802556/sql-percentage-of-total-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the total to calculate the percentage, so use a sub query. To avoid calculating the total over again for every user, cross join to the total calculated once:

```
select customer_id, quantity * 100 / total
from MyTable 
cross join (
    select sum(quantity) total
    from MyTable) x
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the fast help. Of course you should calculate the total.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get total quantity first to calculate the customer quantity percentage.

```
DECLARE @TotalQty int
set @TotalQty = (select sum(Amount) FROM tbltemp)    
SELECT id, Amount * 100 / @TotalQty  FROM tbltemp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef7f66/1)

```
SELECT customer_id, (sum(quantity) / count(quantity ) * 100)
FROM MyTable 
Group by customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient way would be using  `sum () over`. Try this.

```
SELECT 
   customer_id, 
   (quantity * 100)/sum(quantity) over() 
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a sub select:

```
Select customer_id, quantity, quantity / sum(quantity) * 100 per
From
(SELECT customer_id, 
   sum(quantity) quantity
FROM MyTable
Group by customer_id) a
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE @TotalQty int
SET @TotalQty = (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM tbltemp)    
SELECT id, Amount * 100 / @TotalQty  FROM tbltemp
```